# Possible to run scheduled .exe on aws?

Tags: c#, sql, amazon-web-services, exe

In the moment I am running a sql server database locally. Besides I have scheduled a .exe (programmed in c#) via Windows Task Scheduler that is running every night (computer running 24/7) and is downloading an .csv from a external website.

Another .exe is then running every morning to parse this .csv and inserting data into local sql database.

As this is not really "professional" and I am seeking for better solutions I have subscribed for aws.

Question is if above scenario can be done in aws with native methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run Windows Server 2012 on an EC2 server. Then you can install your EXE on that server and run it via Windows Task Scheduler.

If you want to run your program without a Windows server then you might want to look into [Microsoft Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) which is similar to AWS Lambda but with support for the Microsoft ecosystem.

Comment: Ok, that sounds reasonable. I gave aws a try due to the 12m free period. Azure seems to be good fit to my ecosystem (I am also using Visualstudio) but if you need to run sql databases unfortunately it doesn't looks to be economically rational in my case...